# Non-parametric variogram estimators

Tags: nonparametric, variogram, geostatistics

I'm working with overdispersed, count spatial data. The goal is to look specifically at spatial dependence patterns. I'm trying to fit variogram models to empirical variograms, however the only estimators I've seen (implemented in the R package geoR) are the classical and Cressie estimators. Both of these rely on Gaussian distributions.

Any suggestions for non-parametric variogram estimators? Even better if you are aware of one that is implemented in R already!

Comment: Could you explain in what sense either of these estimators "rely on Gaussian distributions" and exactly what a "non-parametric variogram" would be? Few estimators assume Gaussian distributions but *all* are necessarily parametric because they attempt to fit a linear combination of predefined parametric models (e.g., spherical, exponential, linear, Gaussian, Bessel, etc.). This is practically forced on us by the need to assure the fit is positive definite.

Comment: I was under the impression that the classical and Cressie variogram estimators required that the data be normally distributed, is that wrong?

Comment: Cressie's original analysis used normality as a heuristic guide to developing the estimator, but as I recall (I read it almost 30 years ago) it was only a guide and the resulting estimator was intended for more general purposes.  I'm not entirely sure what you mean by the "classical" estimator because--classically--estimation was done by visually fitting a parametric model to plots of empirical variograms, typically decorated with information about lag populations to help weight the points.

Comment: Sorry, by classical I mean Matheron's estimator (I'm going from the terminology in the geoR package). I'm really just looking for ways to summarize spatial dependence in over-dispersed count data, and thought I could use the range value from a model variogram.

Comment: Are you familiar with `GeoRGLM` and the associated book *Model-Based Geostatistics* by Diggle and Ribeiro Jr.? Their model assumes an underlying Gaussian field is linked to parameters of a Poisson or Binomial distribution in a form of GLM. That might be perfect for your application. Their variogram estimator (whose implementation is unfortunately limited) is an MLE.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that package, thanks for the suggestion! Same with the textbook.